# Which .jar should I import so that "import com.android.widget" resolves to a type?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to write some automated test cases for Android
I created a Java project with JUnit 4 and uiautomator.jar + android.jar

but on the line:

```
    UiObject settingsApp = appViews.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), "Settings");
```

I get a red underline saying

```
android.widget cannot be resolved to a type
```

I tried to add

```
import com.android.widget.*;
```

but I get this

```
The import com.android.widget cannot be resolved
```

So which jar file should I add to the build path to make this import work?

Comment: Refreshed, cleaned but no luck

Comment: Oh, the "com." thing worked! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome if I solved the question mark it as a solved :)

Comment: if you are using android studio try alt+enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `android.widget.*`, and not `com.android.widget.*`.

You could also try try cleaning the project, or Ctrl + Shitf + O to organize imports.